# Issue with display()/collect() Large DataFrame In Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, data-processing

Getting The Following Issue In PySpark to perform display()/collect() operation on top of a generated dataframe. The df contains single column & Row (JSON dump of 2GB as a content of the col).

Using databricks 3.4xlarge with 4 workers. Anyone have any known solution of this problem ?

The Error :

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 53, 10.172.250.33, executor 5): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.

Comment: `collect` will collect all data to a single driver node, so it should be used for smaller data. If the data is large after filtering or aggregation to make the data smaller.  What do you want to do with `collect`?  There would be the different functions than `collect` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Use the ``take()`` function instead ``take(NumberOfRows)`` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take.html

Comment: @Emma  -  Actually  trying to get the json content of the data frame in a list using looping through it and performing collect () top of that, ultimately trying to prallelize() convert that df's json content to another data frame.

Comment: Thank you for the stacktrace.  I am not sure what you are trying to do from the description. Could you update the question with some sample data and the expected end result (dataframe?)?